# Returl in Lightning doesnt work

Tags: lightning, visual-flows

Ive recently update our org salesforce to use the new cool lightning ui for the visual flow, yet - its seems that the flow allways return to the start after I click finish - the Returl I put doesnt work!
Does anyone has ideas how can I use a flow via a url button and set the returl so it would work (and keep the lightning UI)?